# Play Store app localization

Tags: android, localization, google-play

I'm about to upload my first app to the Google Play store and when I uploaded the APK to the Developer Console, it says under Localizations: `default + 55 languages`. I don't want my app listed as supporting any of these languages/localizations because it's in English only. What should I do in my app to let Google Play know that the there are no localizations and that the app is in English only?

Comment: Do you have any other directory besides `/res/values/` in your current Android project? For example, `/res/values-de/`, which is the localisation directory for German, etc. Delete the extra directories, compile your project, and re-release it.

Comment: No, nothing like that.

Comment: Probably a new "feature" of Google Play itself. I would ignore it if it does not impact the functionality of your app. Google has a tendency to surprise us from time to time. ; )

Comment: I'd say this is a bug in the Developer Console. I noticed the same thing; `default + 57 languages`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This isn't a problem: Google Play does not let users know what languages are supported by your application and it may be that some of the libraries you use (such as Google Play Services) **are** localized in 55 languages and users would see those translations based on their language, even if the vast majority of your application is not translated.

The only way for a user prior to installing the app to know what languages the app is optimized for is if you add a translation on the Store Listing tab.

Comment: What is the reason for showing it then? creating confusion unnecessarily.

Answer (score 11):

At the time of apk build,aapt used to merge required folder(like res) specified into library that you required for your Application.

Like below code adds google play service usage in your app.

```
dependencies{
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

We can verify this by decompiling apk([using apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)),It shows values folders for supported languages by Your APP +
added library.

In case you only want to show specific languages for your app,You can set it in argument as shown below in build.gradle file.

```
 defaultConfig { 
resConfigs "en", "en_US", "en_UK"          
}
```

This significantly shrink apk size.

Comment: defaultConfig { 
resConfigs "en", "en_rUS", "en_rUK"          
}

Answer (score 2):

Was looking for this solution everywhere, the answer which works and removes localisations from the Google Play store for cordova apps is

```
defaultConfig { 
    resConfigs "en"
}
```

Or change "en" to whichever language you wish.