# Google Play Developer Console shows localizations have changed in my APK since last update

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I've just updated my application, and it's a regular bugfix update, without any added removed localizations or permissions. My app only supports English and Turkish.

However, when I've uploaded my APK, I've got this:

[image]

It shows that I've added 6 new localizations (which I haven't) and removed one permission (which, again, I haven't).

In the contest of configuration, I've updated some libraries with newer versions, removed some unused libraries, and changed some ProGuard settings.

Is this normal? I've seen [Play Store app localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000604/play-store-app-localization) but I'm not really sure if it's the same issue as I've played with ProGuard settings (which shouldn't normally affect localizations after all) and there's also a permission removed, in contrast to that question.

Comment: I can't say much about the localization (sorry), but I do know that using libraries will often require permissions which your base application may not declare. These permissions are added when the application is built, but you won't see the effects of this until uploading to Google Play. By updating to newer versions of libraries, a permission may have no longer been needed and was removed in a newer version. That's likely what you're experiencing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be related to SDKs that I'm using. Those changes are introduced by the updates to the SDKs that I'm using (e.g. Facebook SDK), and had no impact on my application.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too much late for answer this question.
But recently i have passed through the same scenario.
I have updated my apk with older targetSdkVersion 22 which is not matched with my previous updated apk which was 23 on play store.
I have changed it to previous one and it solved that issue.

Hope this will help to someone else.