# Do i need to Build 10 different apk based on 10 languages while doing localization

Tags: android, localization, internationalization, google-play, apk

I am doing an educational app for that i need different language support i am not interested to set language setting inside app. So to localize in app store do i need to build 10 different apk and set the country based on that ? or there is any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to upload in the market 10 different apk if you want to avoid putting the different translations in the app.

But it is strongly recommended that you create different translations and insert them directly into one application.

https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html

[Play Store app localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000604/play-store-app-localization)

Answer (score 1):

Without creating multiple apps, here's your options.

1. [Localize your resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) by putting strings into the `res/strings` by language code.
2. Create a backend that stores all your translations that you can dynamically update without needing to push a new app. (Think - a dictionary app).

**Pros**

1. Ideally, you'd do this anyways for hard-coded in-app strings
2. Dynamic data, minimal pushes to app store

**Downsides**

1. Pushing new app for new strings takes time
2. Constant data transfer kills battery life

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to support localization.

To add support for more languages, create additional values directories inside res/ that include a hyphen and the ISO language code at the end of the directory name. For example, values-es/ is the directory containing simple resources for the Locales with the language code "es". Android loads the appropriate resources according to the locale settings of the device at run time.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

No need to create 10 different apps and upload on store, you just need to add language support by adding string.xml file for each and every language you want to add support. If you are going to create 10 different apps and if there is a very small change in app you have to applied that change in 10 different apps and upload it again to store.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don#t need to build 10 .apk files and upload them. Generally you add required languages to the resources of your app and build the .apk once. This .apk contains all language translations, which you have defined. Then, when user installs your app, it will be checked, whether user's language preference matches the translation languages of your .apk file. If yes, the mathed language will be used. If no, the default language will be used.

[Google support reference](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3125566?hl=en)